# Ubuntu 22.04 top bar text disappear randomly

Tags: 22.04, gnome-panel

After upgrade to 22.04 from 20.04, text in top bar disappear randomy.
Previously, this issue can be resolved by `alt+F2`, and then `r` in the command box.
But now this solution does not work any more, and i have to restart system. Anyone has a better suggestion?

Get some info from https://superuser.com/questions/1164174/how-can-i-restart-the-gnome-shell-on-wayland
and finally I disable gnome wayland. This is only a workaround.

[image]
[image: r result]

Comment: are you using the Unity DE or was either X11 or Ubuntu DE installed during the upgrade process. Maybe reinstall Unity? https://www.makeuseof.com/install-unity-desktop-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: NO. I use wayland. I finally disable wayland in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf, and everything keep the same as previously.  The problem is that I am unable to use new wayland features any more.

Comment: tell me, why did you tag `Unity` if you are not using it?

Comment: I  removed `unity` as I am not sure whether the system still use `gnome` or `unity` when I was writing the post. Sorry for inconvence.